# cxf: wsdl2java created a class that extends Service (javax.xml.ws.Service)

Tags: cxf, wsdl2java

I am new to java WS and WSDL.
I used wsdl2java to create java classes for my web service client and there was a class created with `<Service Name>Service extends javax.xml.ws.Service`

Please let me know what is the use of the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think of this as a 'locator' or 'factory' which can be used for making client-side (proxy) instances of the service. For example (where '*Example*' is the *Service Name*):

```
ExampleService locator = new ExampleService();
locator.addPort( ExampleService.Example, SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING
    , "http://myserver:8080/myapp/services/example" );
// now get the instance
Example example = locator.getExample();
```

Though with CXF you can use utilities such as the `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean` and ignore the `<Service Name>Service` class. Eg:

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.setServiceClass(Example.class);
factory.setAddress("http://myserver:8080/myapp/services/example");
factory.setUsername("user");
factory.setPassword("password");
Example example = (Example) factory.create();
```

Comment: just saw this question was asked many months ago, ah well ... hope it helps someone.